# TeXnicCenter: Icons & text small on 4k screen?

Tags: editors, texniccenter, resolution

I am quite confused that I cannot find any information on this topic as I do not think I'm the only one affected.
Using TeXnicCenter, I recently upgraded to a 4k screen. While making my life significantly brighter, all the icons and the text appears way too small in the editor. I know that the text itself can be re-sized using ctrl + mouse wheel. However, this larger text looks ugly and unfamiliar.
I am using the screen as an add-on to my (FHD) notebook. Trying to use the Windows-setting to scale the entire screen did not work (well, it does for everything but TXC).
Is there any solution to this issue? It's pretty annoying.

Comment: I don't see how changing the font size makes the text ugly, unless the default font always looks ugly but you don't usually notice it.

Comment: I hope that you'll find a workaround, but keep in mind that TeXnic Center is a dead project. The last version was released 10 years ago, so the authors never did the necessary work to support high DPI monitors (which your new 4K monitor presumably is).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when switched to a 4K monitor.
I was able to properly fix the text issue as follows:
In the main menu, go to: Tools > Options > Text Format.
In top window you can select from :  Editor / Navigator / Output
and then click on the button 'Choose' to chose the font type and size.
Then click 'OK' and allow for a few seconds for the change to be reflected on the GUI.

As to the menu icons, I couldn't find any good alternative, as the route :
Tools > Customize > Options and ticking the 'Large Icon' option result in a ugly pixelized big icons (maybe a restart is needed, but I didn't bother to try).

Hope this helps.